# Add Google Map to GatsbyJS with Maps JavaScript API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, gatsby

I'm trying to add a map to my Gatsby project using the Google Maps JavaScript API.

I'm [customizing](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/) the Gatsby `html.js` via a copy of the default one:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

Then, as per the [Google Maps Hello World example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3), *and* after some Googling, I've figured out I needed to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and add the following before my closing `</body>` tag in that new `html.js`:

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    `
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

*(obviously, replacing `MY_KEY` with my actual API key)*

I then created an empty `<div id="map"></div>` in my React component.

This works...sorta. If I navigate away, and return to the page with the map, it will disappear.  I can only see the map if I reload the page that it is on.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 4):

This is the implementation I used to get Google Maps into my Gatsby build:

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';

export const GoogleMap = (props) => {
  const {
    address,
    googleMapsApiKey
  } = props;
  const lat = parseFloat(address.lat);
  const lng = parseFloat(address.lng);
  return (
    <section className="google-map">
      <div className="map">
        { isClient && (
          <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: googleMapsApiKey }}
            defaultCenter={[lat, lng]}
            defaultZoom={14}
          >
            <div
              className="marker"
              lat={lat}
              lng={lng}
            />
          </GoogleMapReact>
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Note the `isClient` conditional rendering is important so that `google-map-react` doesn't break your Gatsby build!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help you or not, but here's what I did:

1. `cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js`
2. Edit `src/html.js` and put `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"
   async defer></script>` at the bottom of the body tag.
3. Put the map initialization in `componentDidMount()` of the component that renders `#map`.

Step 3 could look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Map extends Component {
  initMap = () => {
    new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: { lat: 40, lng: 10 },
      zoom: 5,
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initMap()
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="map" />
  }
}
```

Comment: Im getting `TypeError: window.google is undefined` when I try this approach.

Comment: @Anders make sure you have included the script properly (see step `2`) -- That doesn't seem like an error as a result of the code in step `3`.

Comment: I did include it properly. Endend up using react-google-maps

Answer (score 2):

Here how I got it working on Gatsby (version 1):

1. I have defined a function called `initMap` before the definition of my React component (my page in this case) like this

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.initMap = function() {
    new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: { lat: 40, lng: 10 },
      zoom: 5,
    })
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` is there to avoid breaking the server-side rendering. During ssr, window is undefined and will throw an error if you don't wrap that code into the `if` statement.

2. Using `react-helmet` I injected the Google Maps script tag into the  of my website

```js
<Helmet>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer />
</Helmet>
```

That's it. When the script is loaded (asynchronously) it will call the `initMap` callback and display the map inside the div with the `map` id.

**[EDIT]** This is great if you simply want to display a map and maybe some static marker and infoWindow on it. But if you need to add some dynamic content to it, perhaps your markers depend on some filters, I would recommend https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps

Comment: Solution 2, adding the script via React Helmet component is the best solution, it is somewhat of an anti-pattern from the normal handling of imports via react. Helmet's purpose is to be the alternative choice for script loading and should already be used in your Gatsby template.